# Dynamically create lambda function without explicitly referencing parameters

Tags: python

I want to dynamically create a lambda function that depends on the value of a parameter. However I need the function to treat the parameter as a constant at the time of creation. Here's a simplified example:

```py
a = 2
f = lambda x: x< a
f(1)
a = "foo"
f(1)
```

This obviously  throws an error. A workaround I found is the following:

```py
a = 2
f = lambda x, y=a: x< y
f(1)
a = "foo"
f(1)
```

However this seems ugly and non-pythonic to me. I guess one could at least "fix" the function having two inputs by wrapping it in  a `partial`, but as Hettinger likes to say "there must be a better way".

Comment: the best solution is to not make the lambda depend on a global value. Use a local variable in a higher-order function

Comment: I wouldn't the workaround non-pythonic, but it does something distinctly different from what you want. With that, you can call `f(1, 3)` if you like, whether or not you are *intended* to call `f` with only one argument.

Comment: @chepner That's why I said one could wrap it in a `partial` (from `functools`)

Answer (score 3):

Use another function:

```
a = 2

def make_it(a):
    return lambda x: x < a

f = make_it(a)
```

This ensures that `a` is not a free variable referring to the global scope, but rather a free variable referring to a local variable in an enclosing scope. (The fact that modifying the value of `a` is now non-trival is a bonus.)

There's nothing particularly wrong with using `partial`, either:

```
a = 2
f = partial(lambda x, y: x < y, y=a)
```

although this still exposes the original 2-argument function via `f.func`. (I don't know if you would consider that an issue.)

Comment: I guess this works, but it would clutter the name scope. Moreover, in my case the creation and use of the lambda function occurs inside a loop. Surely I wouldn't want to also put the `make_it` inside the loop. This is why I use a lambda in the first place: because the function is used only locally within a small piece of code. Then with the `make_it` approach, the function definition would be located elsewhere in the code, hurting readability.

Comment: `make_it` can create as many distinct functions as you like. Define it outside the loop, call it *in* the loop.

Comment: > Then with the make_it approach, the function definition would be located elsewhere in the code, hurting readability.

Comment: I just really like to keep things tidy and minimalistic. Having to define a helper function just to the create the function I want to create in the first place just throws me off to be honest.

Comment: Repeatedly defining a new function just to close over a global or non-local variable, rather than defining a single multi-parameter function that you can reuse as needed, hardly seems minimalistic.